# How to block bad/sensitive photos sent by customers through messaging / chat in salesforce

Tags: apex, servicecloud, omnichannel, service, messagingsession

Tried using Sensitive Data Rules but did not work.
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.messaging_block_sensitive_data.htm&type=5

Comment: Screenshots? What are the steps to reproduce the error?

Answer (score 1):

This functionality of blocking sensitive images is not available in Salesforce Messaging at the moment. Please consider logging this as an Idea on [IdeaExchange](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/search#t=All&sort=relevancy).

It takes human intervention to identify this content.